# Как авторизоваться в Instagram.com?

Tags: c#, авторизация, instagram

Только начал изучать C#, теория очень скучна без практики, поэтому решил повозиться и написать приложение для некоей активности в данной сети.

Почитав про POST/GET запросы и посмотрев пару примеров, понял что тут дела обстоят как-то по другому. При анализе запросов на авторизацию там не отправляется логин с паролем, то есть нельзя как в примерах отравлять однострочный запрос, либо я не нашел как.

И появилась идея отправить логин и пароль через форму на сайте, но вот как это реализовать совсем уж не знаю. Логически, это проще, так как необходимо всего лишь отправить два слова и симулировать нажатие кнопки. Но вот как это реализовать нигде не нашел. Если кто-то сталкивался с этим помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

Откровенно говоря затея с формой и всячискими эмуляциями нажатия кнопок выглядит сомнительно и довольно коряво. У инстаграмма есть свой API, который позволяет выполнять всяческие действия, в том числе, разумеется, и аутентификацию. Подробнее [здесь](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать, только вначале нужно зайти на инстаграв через GET и сохранить куки и дальше через POST отправлять запросы. Для этого нужно использовать CookieCollection, HttpWebRequest и HttpWebResponse.